# Does dynamic Mandrill template support iteration over a collection?

Tags: templates, for-loop, foreach, mandrill

I would like to add dynamic content to my e-mail, part of it being a collection of items (e.g. list of books). I would like Mandrill to render each of these items once (e.g. one table row per book). Is it possible to use for-loop in Mandrill somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Mandrill now offers full support for dynamic iteration over a list when you use the [Handlebars templating language](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Here's how to do it:

- [Blog post and introduction — includes examples](http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html)
- [Technical documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This answer is out of date, the feature was added shortly after I wrote this post.**

It is not possible (see the Note at the end [this page](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694286-How-do-I-add-dynamic-content-using-editable-regions-in-my-template-)). Their recommended solution is to use multiple mc:edit sections or variables (one per item) in the Mandrill template.

Since this cannot be done for unknown collection sizes, I decided to pre-render several e-mail parts (like header, body, footer) using a more powerful template language (mustache in my case). I send only these pre-rendered parts to Mandrill via API.

Comment: Seems like since Nov 2014 you are able to do this in Mandrill using handlebars too. http://help.mandrill.com/entries/105267476-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content

Comment: @marcelka, delete outdated answers. :)